# Securize google cloud run API

Tags: python, reactjs, security, google-cloud-run, firebase-hosting

I currently have a web application consisting of a frontend written in react and hosted on firebase hosting and a backend written in python/FastAPI on cloud run.

Currently, the backend is public and can be accessed by all users with the link. I wanted to make it private. So I have:

_required IAM identification
_created a service account for firebase and granted it permission to invoke cloud run
_created a key for this service account and downloaded the .json file

The problems are that :
_I have to add the .json file on the client side, which is not at all secure
_the following import line: `const { GoogleAuth } from 'google-auth-library';` gives me lots of errors. I heard that the `GoogleAuth` library wasn't supposed to be used on the client side, which makes sense.

How to solve the problem of the security of the JSON file and more generally how to protect my API on cloud run so that only my frontend can call it?

Comment: Would this [link](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/) help?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot secure the service account JSON key material client side. Any method that uses a service account client side is insecure.

That leaves you with several options:

A) Use Google OAuth to authorize the client in the browser. The client then uses the HTTP `Authorization: Bearer IDENTITY_TOKEN` header to make requests to Cloud Run.

Review this [document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow).

B) Create a backend that makes requests for the client. The backend code uses a service account for authorization.

Review this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

You need to create Identity Tokens for Cloud Run authorization for either option.

Which method to use depends on how your systems are designed, the number and type of users, the level of security (authorization) you require, and interfaces with other services such as databases, etc.

Comment: I think this (good) answer is more complicated than should be, perhaps Google's fault. Cause requests to Cloud Run flow through Firebase hosting, and you will be billed for the same. I'm surprised there is no easy way to only allow requests through Firebase hosting to invoke Cloud Run HTTP.